Gradle Task Error ( [com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.1] )
A couple of weeks ago my application was running fine and I can see my app on my android phone . Now when I try to run my app it gives me this error:
\*Build file 'C:\\Users\\abdou\\AndroidStudioProjects\\untitled9\\android\\build.gradle' line: 11

* What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> Could not find method implementation() for arguments \[com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.1\] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 31s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1.\*

I didn't change anything or even touched android studio in the past 3 weeks , so I don't know what is causing the error , I would assume that the reason of the error is because I tried to compress my C Drive for space , and I remember that I saw the android studio project files being compressed as well.
First , I tried to decompress my C drive , I made sure that the android studio project files were decompressed as well .
Second , I tried deleting the build and rebuilding again
Third, I tried doing flutter clean , flutter pub cache repair , flutter upgrade --force , flutter pub get , dart pub get and restarting my PC , didn't do the trick .
Here is my build.gradle file:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.1'


    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

